# How to print SSRS ServerReport from vb.net

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

I've been looking everywhere... I can only find how to print a LocalReport, not a ServerReport.

I do not want a print dialogue or anything, I just want it to print.

I have managed to get as far as printing the first page, but I cannot work out how to get the extra pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This VB.Net (2005) class will print a SSRS 2003 report. I suppose it *MAY* be able to handle any SSRS version as reports are passed as arrays of byte arrays, but unfortunately I cannot yet connect to (leave alone render!) SSRS 2005 or SSRS 2008 services to test it.

You should call the PrintReport function passing it the Report bytes (rendered as IMAGE), and the target printer name.

Ok, here's the code (be warned, it's one of my first attempts, and adapted from sample C code, don't remember where in the 'Net):

```
Imports System
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
Imports System.Drawing.Printing
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class clsReportPrinting

Private byaPagesToPrint()() As Byte = Nothing, _
        m_oMetafile As Metafile = Nothing, _
        m_iNumberOfPages As Int32 = 0, _
        m_iCurrentPrintingPage As Int32 = 0, _
        m_iLastPrintingPage As Int32 = 0, _
        m_oCurrentPageStream As MemoryStream = Nothing, _
        m_oDelegate As Graphics.EnumerateMetafileProc = Nothing

Public Function PrinterExists(ByVal PrinterName As String) As Boolean

    'Returns TRUE if the named printer is amongst installed printers, FALSE otherwise
    Try

        PrinterName = PrinterName.Trim.ToUpper

        For Each sPrinter As String In PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters

            'Printers may have UNC names, so we use .EndsWith to deal with \\Server\SharedPrinter
            'if we pass "SharedPrinter" as PrinterName
            If sPrinter.Trim.ToUpper.EndsWith(PrinterName) Then
                Return True
            End If

        Next

        Return False

    Catch oEx As Exception

        'Report error
        glb_oLog.Log(oEx.ToString, clsLogger.enuSeverity.sev_01_Error)
        Return False

    End Try

End Function

Public Function MetafileCallback(ByVal oRecType As EmfPlusRecordType, _
                                  ByVal iFlags As Int32, _
                                  ByVal iDataSize As Int32, _
                                  ByVal dpData As IntPtr, _
                                  ByVal oCallbackData As PlayRecordCallback _
                                 ) As Boolean

    Dim byaDataArray() As Byte = Nothing

    If dpData <> IntPtr.Zero Then

        'Copy unmanaged data to managed array for PlayRecord call
        Array.Resize(Of Byte)(byaDataArray, iDataSize)
        Marshal.Copy(dpData, byaDataArray, 0, iDataSize)

    End If

    'Play the record
    m_oMetafile.PlayRecord(oRecType, iFlags, iDataSize, byaDataArray)

    'Return value
    Return True

End Function

Private Function MoveToPage(ByVal lPage As Int32) As Boolean

    'Check current page does exist
    If Me.byaPagesToPrint(m_iCurrentPrintingPage - 1) Is Nothing Then
        Return False
    End If

    'Set current page stream to desired rendered page
    m_oCurrentPageStream = New MemoryStream(Me.byaPagesToPrint(m_iCurrentPrintingPage - 1))
    'Set curernt stream position to its start
    m_oCurrentPageStream.Position = 0

    'Get rid of any former metafile
    If Not m_oMetafile Is Nothing Then
        m_oMetafile.Dispose()
        m_oMetafile = Nothing
    End If

    'Set local metafile to page
    m_oMetafile = New Metafile(m_oCurrentPageStream)

    'Must always return TRUE
    Return True

End Function

Public Sub pd_PrintPage(ByVal oSender As Object, _
                         ByVal oEV As PrintPageEventArgs)

    oEV.HasMorePages = False

    If (m_iCurrentPrintingPage <= m_iLastPrintingPage) And _
       (MoveToPage(m_iCurrentPrintingPage)) Then

        'Draw the page
        DrawPage(oEV.Graphics)

        'Point to next page
        m_iCurrentPrintingPage += 1

        'If there are more pages, flag so.
        oEV.HasMorePages = (m_iCurrentPrintingPage <= m_iLastPrintingPage)

    End If

End Sub

'This draws the current selected stream into a metafile
Public Sub DrawPage(ByVal oGrx As Graphics)

    If m_oCurrentPageStream Is Nothing Or _
       m_oCurrentPageStream.Length = 0 Or _
       m_oMetafile Is Nothing Then

        Return

    End If

    'Critical section follows (no more than one thread a time)
    SyncLock Me

        Dim iWidth As Int32 = m_oMetafile.Width, _
            iHeight As Int32 = m_oMetafile.Height, _
            oDestPoint As Point = Nothing

        'Prepare metafile delegate
        m_oDelegate = New Graphics.EnumerateMetafileProc(AddressOf MetafileCallback)

        'Draw in the rectangle
        oDestPoint = New Point(0, 0)
        oGrx.EnumerateMetafile(m_oMetafile, oDestPoint, m_oDelegate)

        'Clean up
        m_oDelegate = Nothing

    End SyncLock

End Sub

Public Function PrintReport(ByVal byaReport()() As Byte, _
                            ByVal sPrinterName As String _
                           ) As Boolean

    'Report data is an array of pages. Each page in turn is another byte array.
    Me.byaPagesToPrint = byaReport
    m_iNumberOfPages = Me.byaPagesToPrint.Length

    Try

        Dim oPS As PrinterSettings = New PrinterSettings
        oPS.MaximumPage = m_iNumberOfPages
        oPS.MinimumPage = 1
        oPS.PrintRange = PrintRange.SomePages
        oPS.FromPage = 1
        oPS.ToPage = m_iNumberOfPages
        oPS.PrinterName = sPrinterName

        Dim oPD As PrintDocument = New PrintDocument
        m_iCurrentPrintingPage = 1
        m_iLastPrintingPage = m_iNumberOfPages
        oPD.PrinterSettings = oPS

        'Do print the report
        AddHandler oPD.PrintPage, AddressOf Me.pd_PrintPage
        oPD.Print()

        Return True

    Catch oEx As Exception

        'Report error
        glb_oLog.Log(oEx.ToString, clsLogger.enuSeverity.sev_01_Error, , True)

    End Try

End Function

End Class
```